# How to show Image with http url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-2.0

In sql server database, I have column name Image which has urls like http://www.xyz.com/1009/image1.jpg

Now I want to display it on my datalist. But it is not showing any image. It is might be the case because it is expecting the Image URL to be ~/Folder/abc.jpg

Then how to show the image on the asp.net page when I have image URL, which control I need to use and how?

Comment: You do have <img src="<% ... binding stuff ... %>" />, right? Just making sure..

Comment: I am getting the URL from Database like http://www.xyz.com/1009/image1.jpg. On aspx I have image like  <asp:Image ID="imgmain" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' Width="80" Height="80" />

Comment: OK.. do you see little red X instead of image then? If so, right click it --> Properties (IE) to see the URL it's referring to.. might give us hint on what's going on.

Comment: Hi Shadow Wizard , please provide this answer as a separate so that mark this as an answer.  Thanks

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite done. Feel free to share what you done to help others with the same issue.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: got the previous comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see little red X instead of an image?

If so, right click it --> Properties (IE) to see the URL it's referring to.

Might give us hint on what's going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the image from the database in for the form xzy.com/1009/image1.jpg but want to add the http:// then your code should be

```
<asp:Image ID="imgmain" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#String.Format("http://{0}", Eval("Image"))%>' Width="80" Height="80" />
```

Comment: The URL which I am getting from database already have http extension, as I have mentioned earlier url is like http://www.xyz.com/1009/image1.jpg